# Advanced search / replace Reg ex

Tags: regex

I've done some research on the web, but I didn't found how to do what I want.
Here is my problem:
I have an HTML file with lots of links. I need to add parameters to all the links. So I will ant to add `?param_name=param_value` if it is the first parameter in the link and `&param_name=param_value` if it isn't the first parameter.

I'm using Sublime Text with the search/replace with regex to do this.

I managed to search every link with a parameter and add the new parameter with this:
Search:

```
href="http(.*)\?(.*?)"
```

Replace:

```
href="http${1}\?${2}&param_name=param_value"
```

But what I can't manage is to search in the same way every link **without** a `?` and then add `?param_name=param_value`

Any idea?

Comment: You can find a link without a question mark like this `http[^\s?]+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/DmdaBx/1 Note that in the pattern you currently use `http(.*)\?(.*?)` you can omit the second capturing group as it will not capturing anything. It will also match the last `?` in the string not taking spaces into account which will be matched by the dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a question mark followed by a key=value pair, you don't need a capturing group.

```
http[^\s?]+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YU6Q3A/1)

*Explanation*

- `http` Match literally (or use https?://)
- `[^\s?]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or question mark
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert a whitespace boundary on the right.

In the replacement use the full match `$&` followed by your replacement.

```
$&?param_name=param_value
```

---

Another option could be specifically check if a format of `?key=` does not occur in the link using a negative lookahead.

If it already ends with a `?` and you don't want to double question mark, you could all a negative lookahead for that as well.

```
(?<!\S)http(?!.*\?[^\s=]+=)\S+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tyt5ia/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This seems to work, but I need to keep the href="(reg ex)", because I have in my file also some images (also written with http://url).

And I need the capture group because I'm doing a search / replace (and I don't know any other method than using the ${1} to recall a captured group in a search and replace)

Comment: Sorry, my answer went too fast (didn't know that an enter in comment will post directly).

Thank you for your answer!
This seems to work, but not really in a way I need. I need to keep the href="(reg ex)", because I have in my file also some images (also written with http://url). But that, I can manage.

The biggest problem is that I need the capture group because I'm doing a search / replace (and I don't know any other method than using the ${1} to recall a captured group in a search and replace)

Comment: You are not loosing the href, but this will match it before the closing double quote `http[^\s?]+(?="(?!\S))` https://regex101.com/r/8oK9rL/1 This way you could use. a capturing group `href="(http[^\s?]+)"(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/iwOI4X/1 You can move the parenthesis around to lengthen or shorten the groups capture

Comment: @Gregory If you want to keep the href in the replacement https://regex101.com/r/3BunmP/1

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was trying to do. Thanks you so much. You save me a lot of time :-) !!!